# Synchronised sound effects in libgdx ..?

Tags: android, libgdx, game-engine

Is there any way to synchronize sound effects with sprite sheet animation (consisting 30 frames).

All I need to do is play sound file (2 sec) synchronised with the explosion effects which will last for 2 sec (I presume this might change depending on devices, So no way to assign fixed time).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why would the duration of the sound or the duration of the animation change depending on different devices? Or did you mean the animation?

The device shouldn't play a soundfile more fast or more slow. If you load the asset already before then you just need to play() it and there shouldn't be a delay. At the same moment you will reset your animation time to 0 and then just add the deltatime of the last frame to your animationtime. That way, when lagging, you might also skip frames of the animation and thus keep the sound and the animation synchronized.